# Flutter change local storage path for image

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my application, the photos are saved in the app_flutter and cache folders, but I want to create a folder myself and lose my files in it.

```
 refreshAlreadyCapturedImages() async {
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
List<FileSystemEntity> fileList = await directory.list().toList();
allFileList.clear();
List<Map<int, dynamic>> fileNames = [];

fileList.forEach((file) {
  if (file.path.contains('.jpg') || file.path.contains('.mp4')) {
    print("file path: ${(File(file.path))}");
    allFileList.add(File(file.path));
    debugPrint("FİLE PATH"+file.path);
    String name = file.path.split('/').last.split('.').first;
    print("name" + name);
    fileNames.add({0: int.parse(name), 1: file.path.split('/').last});
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Images and videos are saving to app_flutter file. I want to open a file named image folder and save the files in it.